# Redirect a user to instagram login using POST

Tags: jsf, post, jsf-2, primefaces, instagram

I am working on a website which deals with Instagram pictures.

I have to direct the user to Instagram login page for verification. This process needs my website to send few parameters in the URL, for authorization. The format is given below.

**From instagram docs -**

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

It works fine when I use GET request to hit the Instagram URL.
But now I want to hide these values from the URL and hide it from the user.

So I decided to write a JSF page that will on windows.onload submit the form parameters as hidden and hit the Instagram URL instead. This way I can hide the parameters.

**JSF page**

```
<h:body>

        <h:form  prependId="false">
            <h:inputHidden id="client_id" value="#{applicationBean.instagramClientID}" /><br/>
            <h:inputHidden id="redirect_uri" value="#{applicationBean.instagramRedirectUrl}" /><br/>
            <h:inputHidden id="response_type" value="code" />
        </h:form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function submitPage() {
                document.forms[0].action="#{applicationBean.instagramAuthUrl}";
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </h:body>
```

But this fails from the instagram side, giving code error 400.

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}
```

I checked the values and they all seem to be fine. The only thing I noticed is a "form-id" also being passed. I assume this is causing the authorization failure, Since I need to send only specific parameters. If true how can I overcome this using POST request?

Or am I doing something wrong in my POST request?

Thanks in advance.

*Environment : Java 1.6, JSF 2*

Answer (score -1):

Try passing those values hardcoded and post results.