# Using RESTful web service to hide GET parameters

Tags: http, rest, jsf-2, get, jersey

I had posted a question sometime ago, regarding hiding GET parameters, but never got any replies. 
[Redirect a user to instagram login using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454981/redirect-a-user-to-instagram-login-using-post)

With respect to same issue, I thought I can solve it using RESTful web service to hide my GET parameters.

I am able to make RESTful GET requests to instagram but the issue is, that, instagram after receiving the GET request, it is suppose to redirect back to my web-application to a specified URL.

How do I achieve this using RESTful web services? Because I do get a response including the HTTP status codes but how do I achieve the redirect which is suppose to happen from Instagram.

Thanks

Environment : **Java 1.6, JSF-2, Jersey**

Comment: Why are you trying to hide the URLs from the user? Here's how it's supposed to work. You direct the user to Instagram's authorization URL. Instagram then shows a page to the user asking for their authorization. Instagram then directs the user back to your site (REDIRECT-URI). You don't control what happens when the user is on Instagram's site.

Comment: I understand. But I am not asking any change in Instagrams flow, just a way to hide sensitive data from the user.
This is because I send some data in the URL which is specific to my website. For security purpose I would like to hide them. This data also includes the redirect URL to my website. Isn't it a good practice to do so?